# Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application'] - Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.4

Tags: android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, version

All projects fail to build after updating Android Studio to v3.1.2 from v2.5

```
Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
       > Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.4. Current version is 4.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/userx/AndroidStudioProjects/GarageTinker/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

**I have cleaned my project, restarted Android Studio, and rebooted machine**  I have even deleted the `.gradle` folder in the project.  It's recreated with a subdirectory of 4.1 - attempting to build after delete.

**gradle-wrapper.properties:**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

**Project Structure:**

[image]

**Stack trace:**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/userx/AndroidStudioProjects/GarageTinker/app/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.4. Current version is 4.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/userx/AndroidStudioProjects/GarageTinker/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.4-all.zip

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.


    Exception is:
    org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
            at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:92)
            at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:187)
            at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
            at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:192)
            at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:61)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
            at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:58)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:63)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:103)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:49)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:651)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:133)
            at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
            at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
            at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:246)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:165)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
                at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:107)
                at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
                at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
                at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
                at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
                at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
                at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
                at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
                at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
                at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
                at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
                at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
                at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
                at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
                at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
                at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
                at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
                at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
                at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
                at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
                at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:71)
                at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
                at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
                at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
                at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
                at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
                at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
                at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
                at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
                at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
                at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
                at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
                at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:58)
                at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:33)
                at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
                at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
                at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
                at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
                at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
                at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
                at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
                at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
                at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
                at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
                at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
                at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
                at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
                at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
                at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
                at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
                at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
                at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
                at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
                at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
                at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
                at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
                at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
                at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
                at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
                at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
                at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
                at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:150)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:125)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyType(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:113)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:36)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:80)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:136)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:46)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.java:34)
                at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
                at build_2kqgzlfuw508yc8aqt2bik9zq.run(/Users/userx/AndroidStudioProjects/GarageTinker/app/build.gradle:1)
                at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:90)
                ... 93 more
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.4. Current version is 4.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/userx/AndroidStudioProjects/GarageTinker/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.4-all.zip
                at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.checkGradleVersion(BasePlugin.java:682)
                at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.configureProject(BasePlugin.java:341)
                at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
                at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.apply(BasePlugin.java:277)
                at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.apply(AppPlugin.java:120)
                at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.apply(AppPlugin.java:47)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.java:42)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginTarget.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginTarget.java:50)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.addPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:165)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.access$200(DefaultPluginManager.java:47)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager$AddPluginBuildOperation.run(DefaultPluginManager.java:252)
                at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
                at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
                at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
                at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:144)
                ... 103 more
```

Comment: This sounds similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-192459  (which is for IntelliJ, not Android Studio) - could that be what you are running into?

Comment: @mkobit Similar, but this is in the main project, not a subproject.  There are no referenced sub-projects in this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default gradle pointer wrong.  During update, Android Studio ffailed to update the symlink for gradle:

```
/usr/local/bin/gradle
```

Once I manually updated

```
ln -s /Users/userx/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.4-all/9br9xq1tocpiv8o6njlyu5op1/gradle-4.4/bin/gradle /usr/local/bin/
```

all builds started working again.

Answer (score 1):

`Classpath` version in `build.gradle` project level should be compatible with `gradle` version  in `gradle-wrapper.properties` file.

in my case:

build.gradle project level:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
```

and gradle-wrapper.properties:-

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem using platform IONIC and CORDOVA

I solved this problem doing the following...

First

inside folder of your project

gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=4.7 --distribution-type=all

Second

Open the folder of your project via Android Studio e runs The command

Sync Project with Gradle Files

Third

cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save (if necessary)
ionic cordova platform rm android
npm uninstall cordova ionic -g

At last

npm install -g cordova ionic
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID="your_app_id" --variable APP_NAME="the_name_of_your_app"

And now ...

ionic cordova build android
BUILD SUCCESSFUL